# Sinatra: wrong number of arguments (4 for 0..2)

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I'm currently developing an app with *Sinatra*, *ActiveRecord* and *MySQL*. I'm working on the sign up form, which looks like this:

**app.rb**:

```
post '/signup' do
password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(params[:password], password_salt)

@usuarios = User.new(params[:nombre], params[:cedula], password_hash, "admin")
if @usuarios.save
    redirect './signup', :notice => "Usuario creado exitosamente."
else
    redirect './signup', :error => "Ha ocurrido un error, intente nuevamente."
end
end
```

And the view looks like this, **signup.erb**:

```
    <form id="registro" action="/signup" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Ingrese sus datos</legend>
        <label>Nombre
            <input type="text" name="nombre">
        </label>
        <label>Cédula
            <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="cedula">
        </label>
        <label>Contraseña
            <input type="password" name="password">
        </label>
        <!-- TO-DO:
            Dropdown list con los diferentes tipos de usuarios, i.e.: admin, secretario, etc.
        -->
        <input type="submit" id="registerButton" class="button small">Finalizar registro</a>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Whenever I try to create a new user, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (4 for 0..2)
```

Considering that the table I'm trying to insert the values has 4 columns, I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Any insight to help me solve this inconvenience would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ActiveRecord::new`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new/class) method allows only 2 parameters as arguments, it should be a hash. fix:

```
User.new(params[:nombre], params[:cedula], password_hash, "admin")
```

to:

```
User.new(nombre: params[:nombre], cedula: params[:cedula], password: password_hash, role: "admin")
```

You should always check the documentation, in 99% cases you can find a problem:

> New objects can be instantiated as either empty (pass no construction
>   parameter) or pre-set with attributes but not yet saved **(pass a hash
>   with key names matching the associated table column names)**. In both
>   instances, valid attribute keys are determined by the column names of
>   the associated table – hence you can’t have attributes that aren’t
>   part of the table columns.

```
 new(attributes = nil, options = {})
```

Examples:

```
# Instantiates a single new object
User.new(:first_name => 'Jamie')

# Instantiates a single new object using the :admin mass-assignment security role
User.new({ :first_name => 'Jamie', :is_admin => true }, :as => :admin)

# Instantiates a single new object bypassing mass-assignment security
User.new({ :first_name => 'Jamie', :is_admin => true }, :without_protection => true)
```